# Display username when adding comments My SQL cannot record the username, only display the current login user

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am having the problem of displaying the username. My SQL cannot record the username who added the comments....only display the current login username...what should I do? I don't want customers to enter their name again when they insert comments....

```
<?php

if ($_POST) { 
    $name   = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
    $supplier   = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['supplier']);
    $description = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['description']);
    $remark  = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['remark']);
    $price     = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['price']);
    $image    = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['image']);
    $createdate   = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['createdate']);  
    $author   = ( isset( $_SESSION["username"] ) ? $_SESSION["username"] : "" );



    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO products (name, supplier, description, remark, price, image, createdate,author) VALUES('$name', '$supplier', '$description', '$remark', '$price', '$image', '$createdate','$author')");

    if (!$result) {
        exit(mysqli_error($conn)); 
    }

    redirect('comment.php'); } else { ?>

<?php } ?>
```

SUBMIT.PHP

```
<?php
    include("common.php");
    logincheck();

    $action = (isset($_GET["action"]) ? $_GET["action"] : "");

    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "XX", "XX");
    mysql_select_db("XX");

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $supplier = $_POST["supplier"];
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $remark = $_POST["remark"];
    $price = $_POST["price"];

    $image = '';
    if ( isset( $_FILES['image']['name'] ) && trim( $_FILES['image']['name'] ) != "" )
    {
        $uploaddir = "Products/";
        $image = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

        if ( ! move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $image ) ) {
          die('Image cannot be uploaded');
        }
    }

    switch($action) {
        case "insert": 
            $sql = "insert into products (name, supplier, description, remark, price, image, createdate) values ('$name', '$supplier', '$description', '$remark', '$price', '$image', NOW())";
            mysql_query($sql, $link); 
            break;
        case "save": 
            $id = $_POST["id"];
            $image2 = $_POST["image2"];
            if ($image == '')
                $image = $image2;
            $sql = "update products set name='$name', supplier='$supplier', description='$description', remark='$remark', price='$price', image='$image' where id='$id'";
            mysql_query($sql, $link);
            break;
        case "delete": 
            $id = $_GET["id"];
            $sql = "delete from products where id=$id";
            mysql_query($sql, $link);
            break;
    }
Header( "Location: comment.php" );  
?>
```

Comment: use `userid` instead of `username` and add `session_start();` at the top of the file.

Comment: You have not initialized `$conn` check my answer below .

Comment: Hi thanks for all your ans... if the user is logged in and they insert comment on my page..I would like to display their name in my comment page once they insert...just like now you have logged in stackoverflow.com....every comments you made on this page, will show your name with your comments..how to do that ??should I insert the code in my addcomment page or addcomment_submit page...

Comment: when inserting data you should insert userid then check from users table and match the userid then you can show the username.

Answer (score 1):

You can use put the username in the $_SESSION object once they're logged in.
Then you can just echo the username; for example:
echo $_SESSION['username'];

Comment: Actually, the current code DOES fetch the username from the session.

Comment: HI, but if i want to save the username in my database without asking them to enter again?

Answer (score 1):

This way you can set the session.

```
<?php
// page1.php

session_start();

echo 'Welcome to page #1';

$_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green';


?>
```

You can see the session like this `echo $_SESSION['favolor'];` and it will show `green`

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 0):

In your code the `$conn` is not initialized anywhere. Initialize it like this before trying the query.

`$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");`

Check the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for proper usage.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Not having a connection is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Where does it say that he has a successful connection ? That could very well be the reason for the `INSERT` not working. I don't understand the downvote !! Given the code that seems (and most surely is) like a perfect bug to be causing the problem . Infact the question say "My SQL cannot record the username ". Please read properly. This might very well be the solution @Sven .

Comment: He does not complain about the INSERT adding NOTHING, but the wrong data in one column. That sound like the connection is working to me. Otherwise, PHP would complain loudly about this, too.

Comment: Well the OP has edited it now but the original question did say something about it giving some error and exiting. Which woul only mean the the `INSERT` won't work. Even now the php code above doesn't have a connection handler. You said "Otherwise, PHP would complain loudly about this, too" -- No incase the handler doesn't exist then it wont go in the loop in the first place and will miss the `insert` altogether!! Even now the question is inconsistent in the use of `mysql` on one pice of php and `mysqli` on the other code !! Also the question says about "MYSQL can not record .." whats that ?

Comment: All edits of the question until now only added text, not removed any. You are simply wrong.

Comment: Well maybe cumulatively it did add text .. anyways im not infallible ... what do you make of this "mysql cannot record the username ..." in the question title itself ?

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is `session` , when a user logs in, set a user_login session to 1 ,

and `user_name` `session` to the user name.

before every comment,check if user is logged in or not,

if he is not get the name from form,

if he is, hide the name input and save the user_name `session` in the database.

if you have any problem using `session` comment on this answer, i will explain , if you want

Comment: Hi, if the user is logged in and they insert comment on my page..I would like to display their name in my comment page once they insert...just like now you have logged in stackoverflow.com....every comments you made on this page, will show your name with your comments...

Comment: tell me, do you know how to set $_SESSION when logging in?

Comment: haa..sorry i am an idoit of this...do you mind to explain it?

Answer (score 0):

in the first line of your file(even before any spaces or new lines) you must
add this:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

after the user enters his username and password,
you check  if they match or not,
you have :

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

if username and password matched with username and password stored in database,
do this :

```
$_SESSION['username']=$username;
$_SESSION['log']=1;
```

and then , about your comment page :

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['log']) || $_SESSION['log']!=1) { ?>
Enter your name : <input type='text' name='user_name'>
<?php } ?>
```

now, if user is logged in, he cant enter his name.

i assume your form posts data to `post.php` ,
now in `post.php` you must do this :

```
<?php
 if($_POST['user_name']) $name = $_POST['username']
else $name = $_SESSION['username']
 ?>
```

and then, Note: put `<?php session_start() ?>` in your first line of `post.php`

after all that, you can insert the comment and name of the user in the database.
good luck with that, if my answer helped you, mark my question as accepted.

Comment: Hi there my orginal check login is like this..if I changed to use the above one...the comment page cannot check user is login or not...and still cant display the username as well.........<?php

session_start();


function logincheck()
{
 $email = (isset($_SESSION[ "email" ]) ? $_SESSION[ "email" ] : '');
 if ( $email == "" )
 {
  Header( "Location: login.php" );
 }
}
?>